# My bearded dragon ate BARK?

Tags: health, feeding, reptiles, veterinarian

My bearded dragon is about 8 months old and she looks really healthy. I went back to the pet store to get her some more stuff and the shop owner told me to buy Repti Bark for my bearded dragon. (I'm kind of a noob) So I bought the Repti bark and putted it half of my bearded dragons terrarium. A few days later I was feeding her vegetables and she accidentally ate the bark. I went online to check if my bearded dragon will need to go to the vet or anything but there's no luck. (The vet is very far so I go for special occasions like if he needs a lot of help) I'm not sure if bark is even for bearded dragons... By the way, my bearded dragon is named Peanut (even though Peanut is a girl... I thought she was a boy. It's too late to change her name now). Anyways I just want to know if Bark is not going to kill Peanut, and if Peanut needs to be checked or anything.

Answer (score 4):

She can pass it but sometimes it can get lodged - keep an eye on appetite and stool production, a good indication of a blockage would be vomiting, inappetence, diarrhea or stopped making stool all together.

Remove bark, avoid substrates - your dragon doesn't need tons of humidity so having soil to retain this doesn't pertain to these guys. [Repti-carpet](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HG99D6) is a good choice as it's easy to remove and wash. Substrates are a bacterial breeding ground and as you have notice they sometimes eat it.

Keep her well hydrated, this will help pass the bark - Hornworms and misted veggies are the best for keeping a dragon hydrated. You can also give her a bath in tepid water and massage her belly to help things move along.

Temperature is also an important factor in digestion - 95F - 105F are good basking temps to promote GI motility, be sure to keep the opposite end at a cooler temperature so she doesn't overheat.

Hope this helps, each reptile is very specific to it's needs.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I removed all the Repti bark now and Peanut is looking healthy!